# Is there a reliable way to list all of a class's __slots__?

Tags: python, attributes, slots

I'm looking for a way to reliably get a list of all slot names for a class with `__slots__`. Example:

```
class A:
    __slots__ = ('a',)

print(list_slots(A))  # should output ['a']
```

Of course, this can be done with `list(A.__slots__)`, but unfortunately there are a couple of things that make this more difficult:

- Inherited slots:

  ```
  class B(A):
      __slots__ = ('b',)

  print(list_slots(B))  # should output ['a', 'b']
  ```
- Strings:

  ```
  class C:
      __slots__ = 'xyz'

  print(list_slots(C))  # should output ['xyz']
  ```
- Iterators:

  ```
  class D:
      __slots__ = iter(['d'])

  print(list_slots(D))  # should output ['d']
  ```

As you can see, there are plenty of pitfalls here... is there an implementation of `list_slots` that handles all of these cases correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `inspect.ismemberdescriptor` in this case ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismemberdescriptor)):

```
import inspect

class A:
    __slots__ = ('a',)

class B(A):
    __slots__ = ('b',)

class X(B):
    __slots__ = ('c',)

class C:
    __slots__ = 'xyz'

class D:
    __slots__ = iter(['d'])

def get_slots(cls):
    for k, v in cls.__dict__.items():
        if inspect.ismemberdescriptor(v):
            yield k
    for b in cls.__bases__:
        yield from get_slots(b)

print(list(get_slots(A)))
print(list(get_slots(B)))
print(list(get_slots(C)))
print(list(get_slots(D)))
print(list(get_slots(X)))
```

Prints:

```
['a']
['b', 'a']
['xyz']
['d']
['c', 'b', 'a']
```

EDIT 1: Updated my answer to recursive version of `get_slots()`

EDIT 2: As Aran-Fey pointed out in the comments, this solution works only in CPython.